# Why "/v3/search" is deprecated and what is its replacement?

Tags: api, search, filter, stream

I has been using Bitly API since june 2014. I had implemented "/v3/search" method to filter location and language.

**Can anyone tell me Why "/v3/search" is deprecated and what is its replacement?**

I need same return result values as return by "/v3/search" method.

I will be very thankful.